# How to bind the Id of a select box selection

Tags: angularjs

I have a select box that displays GeoAreaName, I need the GeoAreaId of that selection to populate a input field. I have done something similar with a typeahead input but I am unable to apply it here. 
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZypyANABS9oSYfcMo3Hx?p=preview)

```
<label>Geo&nbsp;Area:</label>
  <select ng-controller="JobMiscCtrl"  ng-model="currentItem.GeoAreaName" ng-options="job.GeoAreaName for job in geoAreaArray">
   <option value=""></option>
  </select>

  <input type="number" ng-model="currentItem.GeoAreaId" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/Ms3qPcwj6dxVF3y75ljZ?p=preview

You had 2 problems.

- Your input field was out of the scope of your ng-controller declaration
- Your ng-options expression needed to be slightly different.

  ```
  <select 
     ng-model="currentItem" 
     ng-options="job.GeoAreaId as job.GeoAreaName for job in geoAreaArray">
      <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  ```